# How to prefer displaying all chinese in kaiti instead of heiti

Tags: macos, big-sur, font, font-book

By default, system-wide, macOS seems to be using its Heiti SC/Heiti TC font for chinese characters. This includes the popup in pinyin keyboard.

How can I switch it to use another font? Songti or Kaiti?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the default system font any more.  Of course you can change it in apps where you compose text. Also in a browser like Firefox where they give you font choices in the preferences.   This old message about the issue may be useful.    https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5124109?answerId=23004659022#23004659022